# CSS Div Margin "Element Collision Detection"

Tags: html, css

What I need to know is how to make my `CSS`configured for div/element collision detection. Now, I realized that other questions asking for collision detection is kind of the opposite of what I need; to **NOT** fix it but to create it, and this is what I mean; I need to have, for example, a `#altnav` element, which is a sidebar, that will continually reach until it hits the `#footer` element using a `min-height: 100%` tag. What it currently does is just reach down until 100%, but stops at a certain point in my page (http://www.thehideout.somee.com/games.html to see what I mean). Another example is my `#wrap` element with a `border-left: 2px solid #000000;` tag reaches past the `#footer` element; which I need it to *stop* at the footer element. So what I'm asking is how can I make the elements detect if it's colliding with another element, and to stop at that element. Priority is key; I would rather have the sidebar with footer fixed first than the `#wrap` and `border` tag. Here's the CSS code for the key elements, followed by the whole css incase another `#element` is causing this.

```
#wrap  {
    width: 760px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

---

```
#altnav  {
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 190px;
    border-left: 2px dashed #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #000000;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
#altnav p  {
    color: black;
    font-family: terminal;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
#altnav h2  {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: terminal;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

---

```
#body  {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 570px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Terminal;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

---

```
#footer  {
    width: 730px;
    height: 60px;
    clear: both;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Terminal, San-Serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
    padding: 13px 25px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
#footer li  {
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#footer a  {
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer a:hover  {
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer #footnav  {
    display: inline;
    width: 310px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 65px;
}
```

---

## Full StyleSheet

```
html, body  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
body {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666666;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'karmatic_arcaderegular';
    src: url('fonts/ka1-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/ka1-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/ka1-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/ka1-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/ka1-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/ka1-webfont.svg#karmatic_arcaderegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
#wrap  {
    width: 760px;
    margin: auto;
}
#header {
    height: 60px;
        width: auto;
    background: #db6d16
                url(VexIMG/header.png);
}
#navigation  {
    width: 760px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    background: orange;
    padding: 0px;
}
#navigation .padding  {
    padding: 2px;
}
#navigation .navlinks  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px; left: 0px;
}
#navigation .navlinks ul  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 760px;
    height: 35px;
}
#navigation .navlinks li {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#navigation .navlinks li a  {
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px 0px 9px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: karmatic_arcaderegular;
    padding: 5px 0px 9px 0px;
}
#navigation .navlinks li a:hover  {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;  
} 
#altnav  {
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 190px;
    border-left: 2px dashed #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #000000;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
#altnav p  {
    color: black;
    font-family: terminal;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
#altnav h2  {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: terminal;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#body  {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 570px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Terminal;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#body .secret img  {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}   
#body .game  {
    padding: 3px 3px 10px 3px;
}
#body .game img  {
    align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    height: 101px;
    border: 2px ridge #ff0000;
}
#body .game caption  {
    padding-left: 1px;
}
#body .space  {
    padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 4px ridge red;
    border-bottom: 4px ridge red;
}
#body .game caption  {
    margin-top: 2px;
    float: right;
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, Verdana, San-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #e9e9e9;
}
#body .game a  {
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#body .game a:hover  {
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer  {
    width: 730px;
    height: 60px;
    clear: both;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Terminal, San-Serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
    padding: 13px 25px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
#footer li  {
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#footer a  {
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer a:hover  {
    font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer #footnav  {
    display: inline;
    width: 310px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 65px;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: @hungerstar Same problem. Didn't help.